# issue custom font, rotation on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, rotation, ios8

I'm testing my app on an ipad 2 with iOS 8 Beta 3 and I noticed two issues about the look and feel of my app.

**Custom font**

What I noticed is that my custom font is not displayed on UIButtons neither UITextView. Obviously, I don't have that issue on iOS 7 or other versions.

What's interesting is that ***some*** UILabels display the same custom font while others don't.

I have the UIFont "declared" in the plist.

[image]

And code like this:

```
        -(void)viewDidLoad{
                    [super viewDidLoad];
                    self.instructionsLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Whitney-Light" size:self.instructionsLabel.font.pointSize];
```

}

Later on, I add an UILabel (same code as above) to the UIView and the UILabel doesn't appear. I believe that now all the UI "initialization" should always be on viewDidLoad.

**Rotation**

I notice that old methods of rotation such as

```
        - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
        - (BOOL)shouldAutoRotate;
        - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

are not called, they are not deprecated I believe.

Does anyone else have these kind of issues?

Comment: Same issue. Neither UILabel nor SKLabelNode displays the correct font. After adding font file to resource and font name to .plist file it isn't even present in UIFont.familyNames() array :(

Comment: Hi , Did you found any solution for this case?

Comment: Sadly I also ran into this problem. I'm guessing my next week will be spent on these undocumented nuances of the new SDK.